# Task using principle of inclusions and exclusions.

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Let $A = \{ 1,.....,100000\}$. Using principle of inclusions and exclusions determine cardinality $B$.
Let $B$ be such subset $A$ that $e \in B \iff e  $ is a number which contains at least one digit from $\{ 3,6,9\}$
I have a problem with counting such numbers.

Comment: What does "contain a number" mean? Do you *digit* perhaps?

Comment: yes, you alright

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve this is to find out how many numbers do *not* contain at least one digit from $\{3,6,9\}$, then to subtract that from $100000$. However, that does not use the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Unless, of course, the formula $|X^c|=|U|-|X|$ is considered part of that principle.

Here is a way that does use the principle.
$$|X \cup Y \cup Z|=|X|+|Y|+|Z|-|X \cap Y| - |X \cap Z| - |Y \cap Z| + |X \cap Y \cap Z|$$

First, it is easier to consider the set from $0$ to $99999$ rather than from $1$ to $100000$: we will get the same answer, and this way we are working with all five-digit numbers (some of them with leading zeros).

We let X be the subset of A "contains at least one $3$" and similarly for B and C. You are then looking for cardinality of $B=X \cup Y \cup Z$. Due to symmetry, many sizes are equal, and we get
$$|B|=3 \cdot |X|-3 \cdot |X \cap Y|+|X \cap Y \cap Z|$$

To find  $|X|$, consider how many numbers in $A$ have the *first* digit $3$, then multiply that by the number of ways to choose one digit out of five (i.e. the permutations of $1$ out of $5$).

To find  $|X \cap Y|$, consider how many numbers in $A$ have the first two digits $36$ (in that order), then multiply that by the number of ways to choose two digits out of five (remembering that order does count: i.e. the permutations of $2$ out of $5$).

To find  $|X \cap Y \cap Z|$, consider how many numbers in $A$ have the first three digits $369$ (in that order), then multiply that by the number of ways to choose three digits out of five (remembering that order does count: i.e. the permutations of $3$ out of $5$).

Then use the formula for $|B|$ above.

I told you the other way was easier! I can think of yet another way that combines the inclusion-exclusion principle with the first method I mentioned. That way avoids counting the permutations and the multiplications. Let me know if you want that.

Comment: yes, but I have to solve it with this principle

Comment: "Let me know if you want that." Please give me that :)


"To find |X∩Y∩Z|, consider how many numbers in A have the first three digits 369 (in that order), then multiply that by the number of ways to choose three digits out of five (remembering that order does count: i.e. the permutations of 3 out of 5)." I don't understand that :(